# refactoring similar functions with access to variables

Tags: jquery, html, css, refactoring, parameter-passing

I have a simple index page that allows you to click a button to change the colors displayed randomly on the background circle divs. The code I've written is working fine, but its really repetitive; I wrote a function for each button, and the functions look identical except for the variables they access.

I'm trying to refactor this into a single function but can't figure out a way to allow the button that is click to access the correct variable to change the background colors. 
For example here is the function for the first button, which accesses the colorList variable that changes the colors to gray spectrum:

```
var colorList1 = [//array of 20 colors]
var colorList2 = [//array of 20 colors]
var colorList3 = [//array of 20 colors]
var colorList4 = [//array of 20 colors]

// .choice-1 is the div class for the first button
$(".choice-1").on("click", function() {
    blankSlate();
    colorList = colorList1;
    $("[id^='nav']").css("background-color", colorList[1]);
    $("#colorChoice").css("background-color", colorList[1]);
});
```

I tried to write something that would access the number in the class name and assign that to a variable that would be accessible to the main function doing something like this:

```
var buttonVar = $("button").attr[0].nodeValue; // get full name of nodeValue
var btnChoice = buttonVar[buttonVar.length-1]; // access number at end of class name
$("button").on("click",function() {
    $('.choice' + btnChoice).on('click', function(){*/
    blankSlate();
    colorList = colorList + btnChoice;
    $("[id^='nav']").css("background-color", colorList[btnChoice]);
    $("#colorChoice").css("background-color", colorList[btnChoice]);
  });
```

...but I'm not sure that this is the right way to go about it, and I'd love some advice about how this type of refactoring is typically handled.

Here's a link to a Codepen showing how it works, and with all the html, css and remaining JS viewable. 
http://codepen.io/a6ftcruton/full/Beizu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `data` attribute to the elements you will click on and pass the name of the collection you want there. You can also store your arrays in an object to make referencing them easier:

```
var myData = {
  list1: [ ... ],
  list2: [ ... ],
  list3: [ ... ]
  // more if you need them...
};
```

Your clickable elements get a single class and the data attribute:

```
<a href="#" class="wow" data-list-name="list2">Click me</a>
<button class="wow" data-list-name="list3">No, Click me</button>
```

Then you can attach to an event listener like so:

```
$('.wow').on('click', function () {
  var el = $(this);
  var my_list_name = el.data('list-name');
  var the_data = myData[my_list_name];
  // do stuff with your data
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CVLma/

Comment: I wasn't sure how to use the data method, but got it after some trial and error. Code looks much cleaner now. http://codepen.io/a6ftcruton/pen/coDIx
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The above scenario points out to `CSS` to refactor. I would suggest you to choose one of the following:

- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com)
- [LESS](http://lesscss.org)

Both of them allow `variables`, `mixins`, `functions` and many other techniques that allow you to make `CSS` that is more `maintainable`, `themable` and `extendable`.